Collecting and showing open source notices in multi module Kotlin Multiplaform Projects
we are starting with a new mobile project and decided to go with Kotlin Multiplatform with shared business logic and native UI.
We would also like to split our app in modules: in both in shared and native part.
I'm now investigating how to collect and display open source notices in resulting Android and iOS apps.
What is the best way to do this?
